# dynamic programming question similar to traveling salesman in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

So I just started exploring dynamic programming a little bit more in depth and I have come across a question which I've been unable to solve for a while now. I would greatly appreciate any help with it.

Find the maximum revenue for a salesman who knows how much revenue he will get in each city per day, given he is free for `len(days_travel)` days;

The input list revenue shows the revenue he will get on a particular day at a particular city (eg. `revenue[0][1] = 2: day 0 and at city 'b'`) and travel days is the number of days he requires to travel from one city to the other (eg. `days_travel[2][1] = 2 days is required to move from city c to city b` and `start` is the city he starts in (at day 0)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

After doing tests I found that the code did not work perfectly
I came to the conclusion that the required efficiency is O(n^3 * d^2)
which is super inefficient.

My code is a sufficient compromise with an efficiency of O(n * d^2)

The final code:

```
        def floyd_warshall_days(days_travel):

    nV = len(days_travel)
    G = days_travel
    # Adding vertices individually
    for k in range(nV):
        for i in range(nV):
            for j in range(nV):
                G[i][j] = min(G[i][j], G[i][k] + G[k][j])
    return G

# The algorithm is similar to Floyd-Warshall
def floyd_warshall_rev(revenue, best_days_travel, city_to_start):

    nV = len(revenue)

    # Set G to array of zeroes by size of nV, When G[0] equals to the starting city revenue
    G = [revenue[0][city_to_start]] + [0]*(nV-1)

    # Set the start city as the best city we can go to in day zero
    StartCityArr = [city_to_start]
    best = city_to_start

    for day in range(1, nV): # For each day
        for city in range(len(revenue[0])): # For each city
            for Previous_Days in range(len(StartCityArr)): # For all previous days

                # The best way from the city we were in a few days ago to the current city
                travel_helper = best_days_travel[city][StartCityArr[Previous_Days]]

                # Normalize zero days travel time to one
                if travel_helper == 0: travel_helper = 1

                # Checks 2 things:
                # 1. Enough days have passed to get to this city
                # 2. The revenue of the current path is greater than the revenue of the best path so far

                if (day - travel_helper) >= Previous_Days and G[day] <= revenue[day][city] + G[Previous_Days]:

                    # The current path is the best one
                    G[day] = revenue[day][city] + G[Previous_Days]
                    # Update the last city visited on the best path
                    best = city

        # Append each day the last city visited on the best path to this day
        StartCityArr.append(best)

    return G


def main():
    #      city: a  b  c  # day:
    revenue = [[1, 2, 1],  # 0
               [3, 3, 1],  # 1
               [1, 1, 100]]  # 2

    #         city:  a   b   c    # city:
    days_travel = [[0, 1, 1],  # a
                   [1, 0, 1],  # b
                   [1, 2, 0]]  # c

    # Finds the best time to travel from each city to another
    best_days_travel = floyd_warshall_days(days_travel)

    # Finds the best travel by revenue from some "start city" for each number of day
    best_revenue_by_day = floyd_warshall_rev(revenue, best_days_travel,1)

    print(best_revenue_by_day)

main()
```

The code make use of dynamic programming,
In each run of the outer loop the algorithm finds the optimal route for any city in a given number of days, which rises each run of the outer loop.

So in the first run the algorithm finds the best route from B under the condition that we have only one day

In the second run the algorithm finds the best route from B under the condition that we have only two days using the previous run

And so on...

So for the current data the output will look like this:

[2, 5, 102]

2 Is the answer for 1 day of job if starting from B

5 Is the answer for 2 days of job if starting from B

102 Is the answer for 3 days of job if starting from B

Comment: Thank you! Been working on this for a few weeks and this is great codes and the comments are so helpful! I'll be running my testcases for it tomorrow :)

Comment: @MarkKI, what if I add a constraint to it, that we don't HAVE to include the city indicated by start, we can travel right on the start day itself. This would produce an incorrect list G.
For example: -> see edit

Comment: @Mateybro You can change the init of the function, and easily change it to the new problem, if you can't figure out how to do that I will be free tomorrow and I'll do it

Comment: I've tried the bottom up approach with your codes as guideline for the past 8 hours but have produced no results. Apologies.

Comment: @Mateybro Please add some contact option in your profile so I can help you one on one

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems simple to understand but complicated to code, at least for a rookie like me. I would approach this from the brute force method. In the example, we are only available for 3 days and travel days count for zero so that greatly reduces the brute of brute force.  Let's have T represent travel days and A,B,C will be the cities.  So then we have:

```
Day0 Day1 Day2  Expected 3-day Revenue
A     A    A       $  5
A     T    B          2 
A     T    C        101
B     B    B          6
B     T    A          3
B     T    C        102 
C     C    C        102
C     T    A          2
C     T    B          2
```

So, we just need to write code for each day linking day, city (or travel), and dollars and then compare the totals. Travel just creates $0 days.  A piece of cake for some of you I'm sure.  if I ever get to 50 points it will be a miracle.

Comment: Brute forcing would give a time complexity of O(N!) (factorial). Hence why the dynamic programming :). The highest complexity seems possible is O(n^2*d), which I'm still figuring out. Thanks for the comment though!